# Unitary operator only if $|a|^2=1$? proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

> Let V=$\mathbb{C}$ be viewed as a vector space of dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$, and let $L_a:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be the map $z\to az$.For which complex numbers $a$ is $L_a$ a unitary map with respect to the scalar product $\langle z,w\rangle=Re(z\bar w)$?

We contend that $L_a$ is unitary if and only if $|a|=1$. This result is obvious from the fact that
$\langle az,aw\rangle=Re(az\bar a\bar w)=|a|^2Re(z\bar w)=|a|^2\langle z,w \rangle$.***Rami Sharkarchi, Solutions Manual For Lang´s Linear Algebra***

**Question**:

**1)** Why cannot $a=-i$? Since $-i^2=1$?

**2)** Why is $\mathbb{C}$ two dimensional?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is two-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$, as every point in $\mathbb{C}$ can be described as $x + iy$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  Slightly more rigorously, set $\{1, i\}$ as forms a vector space basis for $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The OP's trouble seems to believe that $|a|=1$ with $a$ in $\mathbb C$ means that $a=1$ or $a=-1$. Here, $|a|$ denotes t[he modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) of the complex number $a$ hence, of course, $|-i|=1$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)**

$\{ z\in\mathbb C~:~|z|=1\}$ is the unit circle. It contains all complex numbers $x+yi$ where $1=|x+yi|^2=x^2+y^2$. Especially $x=\pm1$ and $y=0$ or $x=0$ and $y=\pm 1$ is possible and therefore $a=-i=0+(-1)i$ is possible.

**2)**

$\mathbb C$ is a twodimensional over $\mathbb R$, since $\{1,i\}$ is a linear independent base of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb R$. Consider that for $x,y\in\mathbb R$ holds $x\cdot 1+y\cdot i=x+yi=0$ iff $x=y=0$.

Comment: Regarding the first question. Do you agree the author proof is incomplete? Once $(-i)$ can also be accepted as an answer.

Comment: I have to see the whole proof. You stated that $L_a$ is unitary iff $|a|=1$. And for $a=-i$ also holds $|a|=1$. But where is the problem?

Comment: The book was the one to state that $L_a$ is unitary iff $|a|=1$. I simply noticed it could also be $a=-i$.

Comment: @PedroGomes But $\lvert -i\rvert = 1$.